# Request header too large while sending image in REST response

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a REST service developed using Spring Boot that is attempting to send back image data to the client, which would then be displayed in the browser. However when i attempt this, i get the following error:

```
2016-09-26 08:40:31.897  INFO 6435 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor     : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:111) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar!/:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractNioInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(AbstractNioInputBuffer.java:267) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar!/:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1013) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar!/:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar!/:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar!/:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar!/:8.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar!/:8.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

My service code is as follows:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/com")
        public String handleCompare(@RequestParam("testid") String test,
                                    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) throws IOException {

        File f=new File("Sampletest.jpg");
        BufferedImage origImg=ImageIO.read(f);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(origImg, "jpg", baos );
        byte[] imageInByte=baos.toByteArray();
        byte[] encoded= Base64.encodeBase64(imageInByte);
        String encodedString = new String(encoded);
        model.addAttribute("webcamattr", encodedString);
        return "resp";
      }
```

The relevant part of "resp.html" is as follows:

```
   <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><b>Response Image</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="webfile : ${webcamattr}">
                <td> <img width="300" height="300" src="data:image/jpeg;base64" th:src="${webcamattr}"></img></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

My application.properties file is as follows:

```
multipart.maxFileSize=10Mb
multipart.maxRequestSize=10Mb
```

The file that I'm trying to send is just 19KB in size but I'm not sure why it is throwing a large request header error. Could you please help in identifying what am I doing wrong? Is the image data being passed in the request header? If so, how can i send it in the response body?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you showing us `resp.html`? The POST request to `http://server/context/com` is being reject *before* your `handleCompare()` method is invoked. The client is sending bad data, so check the client code, and/or log the request headers.

Comment: @Andreas the request is not getting rejected. The call to handleCompare is successful as I have verified this. This error is being encountered when the response is sent to "resp.html"

Comment: Really? Because that stacktrace would indicate otherwise.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah I know that is confusing. I have some workflow code inside handleCompare (which I havent included here) that gets invoked successfully. So i assume the call is successful.

Comment: So how do you know that the request that caused the error is the *same* request that successfully invoked your `handleCompare()` method?

Comment: I'm placing only one request at a time. Also, If I comment out the model.addAttribute() line and remove the webcamattr code from resp.html, it works perfectly. Please do let me know if this is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not the from the request to `.../com` that invokes the `handleCompare()` method. That request completes normally, and sends an HTML page to the client browser.

The client browser will then try to render that page, and will see the `<img width="300" height="300" src="sojghsirhsdfoh...bytes removed...daskfgdskfg=="></img>` tag. The browser will therefore send another request to the server to URL `.../sojghsirhsdfoh...bytes removed...daskfgdskfg==` to get the data for the image to be displayed.

*That* request is causing the error, because the URL to too long. This is backed by the callstack showing the error occurs during a call to `parseRequestLine()`.

The `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag is built incorrectly. If you intended to build a Data URI, the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` should be a prefix to the value, but `th:src` *replaces* the `src` attribute. Also notice that you need a `,`.

If possible, you should avoid using Data URIs. Define another URL for retrieving the JPEG image, and change the `src` attribute to be that URL. Especially if the image is static, like your code shows.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense! According to your suggestion, would I have to define a new REST api that retrieves the image byte array and call this API from src ?

Answer (score 3):

Which application server are you running this? You are missing the `maxPostSize` property under `http-listener`.

In case you are using Tomcat, it can be achieved with something like:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" **maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" maxPostSize="4194304"**  
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

If the server is managed by Spring Boot, try adding these to your application.properties instead:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=1Mb # Max file size
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10Mb # Max request size
```

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot with the integrated Pivotal server and therefore I believe we need to modify application.properties instead of server.xml

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: tried that. Unfortunately it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2):

@mhasan For anyone facing the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large` error in a spring boot application, setting the `server.max-http-header-size` property in your `application.yml` should resolve the problem:

```
server:
    # increase max http header size to 128KB to allow large headers 
    # e.g. due to keycloak authentication tokens, cookies, etc.
    maxHttpHeaderSize: 131072
```

This can be particularly useful when the request header size exceeds the default limit (8KB) of `Tomcat` / `Coyote` (See https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/AbstractHttp11Protocol.java#L166), e.g. due to authentication tokens (Keycloak, etc.) or any cookie with larger content, possibly also set by a different application on the same domain.